# Workflow auto publish on intermediate state

Tags: publishing, workflow

### Is is possible to perform autopublish of item on intermediate, not final state of sitecore workflow?

Sitecore 9.0.1, Admin user.
I have custom workflow with the following states:

1. Editing

   - Submit
2. Reviewing

   - Approve (autopublish item to **web** database)

     - Auto Publish Action
   - Reject (move item to Editing)
3. Published

   - Approve (autopublish item to **production** database)

     - Auto Publish Action
   - Reject (move item to Editing)
4. On Production (final state)

When item goes from `Reviewing` -> `Published` state (by approval) - it's not being autopublished. It works only from `Published` -> `On Production`.
I've tried to achieve this by `Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.PublishAction`

[image: workflow]

I also tried to wrote custom processor for this and do publish via code:

```
PublishManager.PublishItem(dataItem, targets, master, isDeep, false, publishRelated);
```

or

```
var po = new PublishOptions(master,
                           targetDb,
                           PublishMode.SingleItem,
                           lang,
                           System.DateTime.Now);
po.RootItem = dataItem;

Publisher publisher = new Publisher(po);
publisher.Publish();
```

Code executes, but nothing publishes, no errors in logs.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Sitecore never publishes item which is not in a final workflow state. In your scenario this would mean both Published and On Production states would have to be final states. You may try that but I have no idea if this will work for you.

Comment: Btw cross posting is not recommended. I suggest you remove one of your questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598352/sitecore-workflow-auto-publish-on-intermediate-state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The piece you're missing is that on that intermediate workflow state (**Reviewing**, in your example) you need to set the `Preview publishing targets` field:

[image: Preview publishing targets field]

Check your `web` target in that field for your **Reviewing** state and the auto-publish action should work as expected.

Note: if your target does not show up in this list, you may need to navigate to the publishing targets (`/sitecore/system/publishing targets`) and check the **Preview publishing target** checkbox:

[image: Preview publishing target field]

Comment: Now it works, thank you! But it works only when I use `Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher`. If I use `Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager` the item is skipped and not being published. Currently, I don't know the reason of this.

Comment: PublishManager works with the below code..  
 Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home");
 Sitecore.Publishing.PublishOptions opt = new Sitecore.Publishing.PublishOptions(Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master"),
     Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web"), Sitecore.Publishing.PublishMode.SingleItem, item.Language, DateTime.Now);
 opt.RootItem = item;
 Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.Publish(new Sitecore.Publishing.PublishOptions[] { opt });